# Show that the linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear by showing that it is a matrix transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$ denote rotating a plane vector $45$ degrees counterclockwise about the origin.

Show that this transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is linear by showing that it can be represented as a matrix transformation.

Comment: You might be interested in a $\LaTeX$ markup for "math blackboard" font for the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ so that you don't confuse this with the symbol for your rotation mapping $R$.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily proof the general result for any angle of rotation $\theta$.

Any vector $\vec v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented as:
$$
\vec v=\begin{pmatrix}
v \cos \alpha \\v \sin \alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$$

[image]

and the vector $\vec v'=R_\theta(\vec v)$, rotated by an angle $\theta$ is ( see the figure):
$$
\vec v'=\begin{pmatrix}
v \cos (\alpha+\theta) \\v \sin (\alpha+\theta)
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
v \cos \alpha \cos \theta-v\sin \alpha \sin \theta \\v \sin \alpha \cos \theta+v\cos \alpha \sin \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and a simple inspection shows that $\vec v'$ is obtained from $\vec v$ multiplying by the matrix:
$$
R_\theta=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta& -\sin \theta\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end {pmatrix}
$$

In your case $\theta = 45°$.

Answer (score 0):

To find the matrix of a linear map, you need to look at what happens to the basis vectors.

In this case, I imagine you'd use the "standard" unit vectors $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ as your basis.   If you rotate each of these vectors 45 degrees counterclockwise about the origin, you will see that $(1,0)$ is mapped to $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$, and $(0,1)$ is mapped to $(-1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$.  These vectors become the columns of your matrix.